# How to set datetime to end of day in java

Tags: java

I want to set datetime of day as: startDate=2018/03/28 00:00:00 and endDate=2018/03/28 23:59:59

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59");
    String str1=sdf1.format(cal.getTime());
    String str2=sdf2.format(cal.getTime());
    Date startDate = sdf1.parse(str1);
    Date endDate = sdf2.parse(str2);
```

My problem:program is working and output  endDate=2018/03/28 00:00:00

Would you please point out any mistakes to me in code?

update:
i used debug and it's working correct with

```
String str2=sdf2.format(cal.getTime());//2018-03-28 23:59:59
```

but when change string==>date is not correct with output `2018/03/28 00:00:00`

Comment: I suggest that you use [Calendar::set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int))

Comment: Any reason for using Calendars? Are you allowed to use java 8's time api?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to initialize [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instances from a formatted string with both date and time then time codes should be added to the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern to parse strings in that format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date startDate = sdf.parse("2018-03-28 00:00:00");
Date endDate   = sdf.parse("2018-03-28 23:59:59");
```

If you want to simply set the hour, minute, and second on the current date then use a [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance and set fields on it accordingly.

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
 cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

 Date startDate = cal.getTime();
 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
 cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
 cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
 cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999)
 Date endDate = cal.getTime();
```

And next output the Date in a particular format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(startDate));
System.out.println(sdf.format(endDate));
```

**Output:**

```
2018/03/28 00:00:00
2018/03/28 23:59:59
```

**Dealing with time zones**

If time zone is other than the local time zone then it's a good idea to be explicit with what timezone you're working with. Calendar and SimpleDateFormat instances must be consistent with what timezone you're dealing with or the date and/or times may be off.

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
```

A substitute for *SimpleDateFormat* is using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class found in the newer `java.time` package added to Java 8.

Comment: But I want to change Date,no fixed .What else can I do?

Comment: see my comment below your question

Comment: Rapidly python will replace java in this area as well if it makes hell to just change the time, now when we try to do all this, we will start facing timezone issues and much more.. its total waste of that many lines to simply update the time

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59");

    SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    String str1=sdf1.format(cal.getTime());
    String str2=sdf2.format(cal.getTime());
    try {
        Date startDate = sdf3.parse(str1);
        Date endDate = sdf3.parse(str2);
        System.out.println(str1);
        System.out.println(str2);

        System.out.println(startDate.toString());
        System.out.println(endDate.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

OUT PUT
2018-03-28 00:00:00
2018-03-28 23:59:59
Wed Mar 28 00:00:00 ICT 2018
Wed Mar 28 23:59:59 ICT 2018
```

I think, maybe sdf1 and sdf2 don't provide clear format.
So change time to HH:mm:ss.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the `Date` values for today's start and end times, you don't need to use date formatting utilities (like `SimpleDateFormat`) at all:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
Date startDate = cal.getTime();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
Date endDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: According to Javadocs *Use set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) to reset the hour value.*

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem like this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59");
    String str1=sdf1.format(cal.getTime());
    String str2=sdf2.format(cal.getTime());
    Date startDate = sdf1.parse(str1);
    Date endDate = sdf2.parse(str2);
    String startDateTime  = sdf1.format(startDate);
    String endDateTime = sdf2.format(endDate);
    System.out.println("startDate ----->" + startDateTime);
    System.out.println("endDate ----->" + endDateTime);
```

The output of this

```
startDate ----->2018-03-28 00:00:00
endDate ----->2018-03-28 23:59:59
```

Hope this is what you want.